# javascript split() of a attribute src of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, split

I have this:

```
<iframe src="http://999.999.99.99/reporting/report.php?rid=2&gid=6&ftid=0&fid=1000&gty=1&ltid=1&lid=1000&mode=7&width=220&sid=0&cc=666666,ffa401">
```

I tried `split()` in getting the value between `rid=` and `&` but it does not get what I wanted. I only wanted the value between those two. Please help.

This is my code so far:

```
var source = 'http://999.999.99.99/reporting/report.php?rid=2&gid=6&ftid=0&fid=1000&gty=1&ltid=1&lid=1000&mode=7&width=220&sid=0&cc=666666,ffa401';
var rid = source.split('rid= &').pop();
alert(rid);
```

Comment: Consider posting the code that you've actually tried. Maybe you're making only a minor mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a simple regular expression:

```
var rid = src.match(/rid=(\d+)/)[1];
```

Comment: But it'll failed if it contains `masterid=4&rid=2`

Comment: Mmmm, but it doesn't. Anyway I'm sure OP can make it work if not there are other "better" answers.

Answer (score 3):

Using a **URL parser** described [here](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/61/parse-query-string-by-pure-javascrirpt/).

```
var parts = getUrlParts(url);
var rid = parts.rid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression

```
var str="http://999.999.99.99/reporting/report.php?rid=2&gid=6&ftid=0&fid=1000&gty=1&ltid=1&lid=1000&mode=7&width=220&sid=0&cc=666666,ffa401";
var re = /[?&]rid=([^&]+)/i;
var part = str.match(re);
console.log(part[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match against a regular expression, but if you want to do that with split, try:

```
var a = src.split("rid=")[1].split("&")[0];
```

Comment: Fails on `masterid=4&rid=2`

Comment: Yes, it does. It was intended to work for the given example, be clean and unsafe ;).

Comment: Before answering on SO make sure its **safe** and **never unsafe**

Comment: I don't think I agree with you. I like it when the answers are somewhat inspiring, not only showing you the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
var rid = src.substr(src.indexOf('rid') + 4).split('&')[0];
```

Comment: Fails on `masterid=4&rid=2`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys, I can really count on you guys here in SO.

So far, from your answers, I have used `match()` and it worked fine. Really, thank you guys. :)